# Azure Automation Account - Connect-MGGraph - Insufficient priveleges

Tags: powershell, entra

I have created an Automation Account and assigned the Contributor role (this account will be used to update Entra from our HR System). I have specified System Managed Identity.

[image]

Here is the role assignment:

[image]

Connect-MGGraph -Identity successfully connects, but a simple get-mguser fails with insufficient privileges.

System.Exception: [Authorization_RequestDenied] : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Do I need to do more with the system-managed identity?

Comment: Does it make a difference of you explicitly include the required authorization scopes: `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All" ...`?

Comment: Having a Contributor Role assigned to a Subscription means absolutely nothing, ARM and Graph are 2 completely different APIs.

Comment: When I add scopes it does not connect, the -identity switch doesn't accept them.  I am going to add explicit additional permissions for the account to test.

Comment: Please clarify in your question what PowerShell Runtime are you using for your Runbook and what version of the Microsoft.Graph.Authentication Module do you have installed for that Runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the following command for the system-managed identity to grant the permissions:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Application.Read.All, AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All, RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory

$managedIdentityId = "YourIdentity"
$roleName = "Role You want to add from below"
#"Group.ReadWrite.All"
#"User.ReadWrite.All"

$msgraph = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
$role = $Msgraph.AppRoles| Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $roleName} 

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $managedIdentityId -PrincipalId $managedIdentityId -ResourceId $msgraph.Id -AppRoleId $role.Id
```

This will grant the permissions required to the Managed identity object.